# Java Thread interrupt(). Is it normal exception?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am starting my Thread like this:

```
public void startTask(Runnable r)
{
    running = true;
    Log.i(tag, "-----------start.Runnable-----------");

    final Thread first = new Thread(r);
    currentTask = first;
    first.start();

    Thread second = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                first.join();
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){

            }
            running = false;
        }
    });

    second.start();

}
```

And when I want to cancel current operation, I am doing such with a Theread according to this article: http://forward.com.au/javaProgramming/HowToStopAThread.html  :

```
public void cancelTask()
{
    Log.i(tag, "-----------cancelTask()-----------");
    try{
        currentTask.interrupt();
        running = false;
    }
    catch(SecurityException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Application is still running after cancelTask, but I have exception:

```
12-05 20:29:00.274: W/System.err(13533): java.lang.InterruptedException
12-05 20:29:00.274: W/System.err(13533):    at java.lang.VMThread.sleep(Native Method)
12-05 20:29:00.294: W/System.err(13533):    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1047)
12-05 20:29:00.294: W/System.err(13533):    at java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.sleep(TimeUnit.java:331)
12-05 20:29:00.304: W/System.err(13533):    at com.rsd.myfirstapp3.ProgressServiceActivity$2.run(ProgressServiceActivity.java:174)
12-05 20:29:00.314: W/System.err(13533):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

.

**Is it normal exception in such operations with threads?**

Comment: Erm, yes ... that's what interrupting a thread *does*.

Comment: [www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

A thread is stopped on its own or it is stopped by external process. Means a thread finishes its execution after doing whatever it is doing, at this time InterruptedException is not thrown (which is obvious) . But parent thread (a thread which starts a thread) may want to stop the executing thread in between its execution, in this case an exception InterruptedException is thrown and this exception is received by a thread. This is mainly because this tread wants to do something (cleaning resources, closing IO etc..) when it is being stopped by external process / parent thread. [Refer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html)